# Writing to console from ASP.NET Core middleware pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

Is it possible to write to console from ASP.NET Core middleware pipeline? I want to pass some data from middleware to console. But the following sample code ignores the Console.WriteLine() call in the first delegate but writes response to the browser from 2nd delegate. Here is a part from Startup.Configure method...

```
app.UseRouting();

            app.Use(async(context, next) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message for console");
                await next.Invoke();                
            }
            );

            app.Run(async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from 2nd delegate.");
            });
```

Comment: You might be taking the wrong approach to this, there are lots of ways to send data like that, often for logging/debugging purposes. What are you trying to accomplish by sending data to the console?

Comment: This is for learning how the middleware works. I want to get information such as Console.WriteLine("Endpoint has route pattern: " +
                routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.RawText);

Comment: If you're using this with a debugger attached, you can output to the debugger or IDE's screen. You can also step through it in the debugger, if this is just about learning. If you're running it on it's own, you can output to a file, like a txt. Or did you want the live data streaming to you to see?

Comment: The Console provider can help log output to the console. You can get the log in the Debug output window or in the console window when the app is run with `dotnet run`. For more information, you can check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging-output-from-dotnet-run-and-visual-studio.